# CoffeeScript - Binding Click Events to Dynamically Loaded Objects With JQuery On

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript

Working on rewriting the front-end of my site in Coffeescript. I understand how to bind a click function to a class.

```
$('.song').click ->
    //code
```

However, I am running into some problems with dynamically loaded content. I know in JQuery, the solution to this would be to use the "On" function like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.song', function(){
    //code
});
```

But I am unsure on how this translates to coffeescript. I am under the impression that the rocket arrow -> translates to an anonymous function in javascript, but how does that work with if the function is one of the parameters? I've tried out quite a few different syntax and none of them seem to work, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.song', ( ->
    ### code ###
));
```

Translates to this JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.song', (function() {
  /* code */
}));
```

Note that you may want to use the `=>` operator instead of `->`; using the double arrow also binds `this` to the event handler (equivalent of using jQuery's [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)).

Comment: @Epeli, while your edit is also a possibility it is not my preference. Depending on the contents of the function, CS has trouble finding the end, which is resolved by putting the braces explicitly. I find the ambiguities in CS annoying; `$(document).on` for instance returns `on`without invoking it, `do $(document).on` invokes it, `$(document).on something` also invokes it, and `do $(document).on something` will invoke the result. Using explicit braces for arguments makes this muss less prone to errors IMHO. I'll therefore edit back. Feel free to post your own - I'll upvote it. ;)

Comment: Roger and sorry. It seemed rather obvious edit since you rarely see CS code with brackets if the code execution order is clear. Like in this trivial example.

Comment: @Epeli, fair enough, which is why I explained myself. Having thousands of lines of CS code running in a modular SPA and seeing my devs struggling with some of the explained behavior I have decided to require the parens for method invocations in my organization, at the same time I'm banning the use of `do`. This in fact helps to keep the code quality high, especially during code maintenance.

Comment: @Lucero thank you - in the above examples, how does one operate on the element that was clicked within the subfunction ? any advice much appreciated

Comment: @BKSpurgeon The `event` parameter is passed to the function, and on it you have the [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property, which should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 21):

Usually one don't use brackets in CoffeeScript if the execution order is clear without them. So this can be written like this:

```
$(document).on 'click', '.song', ->
    ### code ###
```

But of course use brackets always when the execution order is not obvious.

Comment: This should be **the** answer!

Answer (score 4):

JS2Coffee can help with these type of questions:

http://js2coffee.org/

You need to be a little careful with js2coffee, as it sometimes stumbles on fairly tricky JS code, but it's surprisingly accurate, and it will usually at least get you pretty close.